# How to get elements from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, get

I'm trying to make a `node.js` application that takes the input from a text box in an HTML file. I want to store this value in an array, although I'm not sure how. My overall goal is to make a chat application and I assume there is some easier way to get the input without having to reference an HTML file.

Also, are there any templates for an html file because I'm not very skilled enough with HTML to make a decent-looking webpage. So if there is some template I could use, everything would look better.

My code:

```js
var events = require('events');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var msg = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.read('/', function() {

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port " + 3000);
});
```

```css
#firstHead {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id='firstHead'>
    This is a header!
  </h1>
</header>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="inText" placeholder="Enter text here" />
</body>
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Header should be inside the body tag

Comment: If you want to create a chat application, there are better ways to go about it.  Check out https://socket.io/ or similar technologies.

Comment: Okay, I'll just do that, I just wasn't sure if you had to make a text box with HTML, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML code has so many mistakes. This the correct version of your code (You won't be using it, it's just to give you an idea of what mistakes you've done):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #firstHead {
            font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id='firstHead'>
                 This is a header!
             </h1>
    <form id="msg" method="GET" action="/msg">
        <input type="text" name="msgContent" id="inText" placeholder="Enter text here" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now this HTML page will send input contents to `localhost:3000/msg` as a POST request [See here for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), the problem here is that page will be refreshed or redirected (depending on your implementation, you should in this case use AJAX if you want [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)). Even if you used AJAX it will be hard for you to implement a chat application using HTTP requests. It would be a better idea to use WebSocket protocol to achieve this functionality. There's a module called Socket.io that will help you a lot. It has an event-driven system as it's great for real-time applications, you can check their official website; they've have an example of a chat application written in few hundred lines of code.

Now let's move to your server-side code, firstly .. there's no method of express called `read`, here's a working version of your code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var msg = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //You should use some template engines like EJS or Pug to render your HTML page with messages or the user will see nothing
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/msg', function(){
    msg.push(req.query.msgContent);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port " + 3000);
});
```

The above code will work as it should but you'll see nothing in the client-side cuz you didn't render (or send msg array to client-side script to embed it). I'm just trying to make things clear to you not give you an implementation of your idea

I hope this helped you a little.

Comment: This isn't correct either, you dont have a `<header>` in a `<html>`, it should be a `<head>`!

Comment: Ops, I didn't pay attention to it :p